# Converting integer to HH:MM:SS

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to merge two separate integers and convert into a 24 hour format hh:mm:ss. Below is my code:

```
    var hr = 5;
    var min = 30;
    /**convert to hh:mm:ss*****/
    var combine_time = new Date(hr + ":" + min + ":" + "00");
    
    alert(combine_arrive);
```

However, my javascript show it as invalid date. Can anyone guide me? Thank you

Comment: it is new Date() not new date() and what is arrive_hr and arrive_min please share the rest of your code

Comment: @Alex sorry. typo error. I have edited my question

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you meant this?

We cannot know if 5 is 5am (05) or pm (17) unless you tell us

```js
const arrive_hr = 5;
const arrive_min = 30;

const pad = num => ("0"+num).slice(-2);
const combine_time = `${pad(arrive_hr)}:${pad(arrive_min)}:00`;
console.log(combine_time)
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var hr = 5;
var min = 30;
 
var timeString = `${hr}:${min}:00`
var combine_time = Date.parse('1970-01-01 ' + timeString);
    
alert(combine_time);
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the documentation: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date

Use the setter functions.

```
var hr = 5;
var min = 30;

var combine_time = new Date(); // create new Date and assign value

// as follows you set hr, min and secs
combine_time.setHours(hr);
combine_time.setMinutes(min);
combine_time.setSeconds(0);
```